# Will a BigEasy driver handle 14 amps?

Tags: arduino, current

I'm getting some conflicting information regarding the BigEasy stepper driver. I have a 24VDC 14.6A electromagnet that I need to toggle. I have a few Arduino Mega's and a box full of BigEasy stepper drivers that I would like to utilize to accomplish this as I'm extremely short on time.

I know the BigEasy can take the 24VDC but what about the 14.6 amps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Big Easy driver](http://www.schmalzhaus.com/BigEasyDriver/) is based on the [Allegro A4983](http://www.allegromicro.com/Products/Motor-Driver-And-Interface-ICs/Bipolar-Stepper-Motor-Drivers/A4983.aspx) chip, which can handle only up to 2 A per phase. So no, it will definitely not handle 14 A (even if you use both of the internal H-bridges in parallel), and the chip's built-in overcurrent protection circuitry will prevent you from consuming anywhere near that much current.

But for your situation, a stepper motor controller is way overkill for toggling solenoids. A [mechanical relay](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/uploads/Main/relays.pdf), an [SSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_state_relay), or even a [MOSFET](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Learning/SolenoidTutorial) of sufficient current capability will be more than adequate to control the electromagnet.

---

Are you sure you have a 24 VDC solenoid that consumes 14.6 A? That would mean that the coil resistance is only 1.64 ohms, which seems really low to me.

Comment: That's what I thought but someone at SparkFun told me the docs were wrong and it could handle it. Just wanted to make sure. Thanks In silico

Comment: Just to add on here... this is way overkill for toggling a solenoid.  SparkFun might say it will work, but it seems like you're taking on a ton of complexity for what boils down a basic on/off switch.